# Suppose $P(|X| < 1) = 1$ and $P(|Y| = 2) = 1$.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Suppose $P(|X| < 1) = 1$ and $P(|Y| = 2) = 1$.

Then which of the following is true?

1. The standard deviation of $X$ is smaller than that of $Y$.
2. The mean of $X$ is smaller than that of $Y$.
3. The variance of $X$ is larger than that of $Y$.
4. The median of $X$ is equal to the median of $Y$.
5. None of the above is correct.

Since $X$ is between $-1$ and $1$, and $Y$ is neither $-2$ or $2$, so that the s.d. of $X$ is smaller than that of $Y$, isn't it?

Comment: I think you are missing some information. If $Y$ is identically $=2$, then it will have variance $0$.

Comment: @jameselmore $Y$ can be equal to $2$ or to $-2$.

Comment: @JimmyR., sure.. my point was that there are situations where $P(|Y|=2) = 1$ and $\text{Var}(Y) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct counterexamples:

1. Let $Y\equiv 2$ and $X \sim U(-1,1)$. Then $Var(X)>0=Var(Y)$.
2. Let $Y \equiv -2$ and $X\sim U(-1,1)$ or simply $X\equiv 0$. Then $E[X]=0>-2=E[Y]$.
3. Let $Y\in\{-2,2\}$ with $P(Y=-2)=p=1-P(Y=2)$ and $p>0$ and $X\equiv 0$. Then $Var(Y)>0=Var(X)$.
4. Let $Y\equiv2$ and $X\sim U(-1,1)$. Then median $Y=2$ and median $X=0$.

Go with 5.

Answer (score 2):

For (1): show you can have, for instance, $\operatorname{var} Y = 0$ and $\operatorname{var} X >0$, or $\operatorname{var} Y >0$ and $\operatorname{var} X = 0$.

For (2): Show you can have $\mathbb{E} X = 0$ and $\mathbb{E} Y > 0$, or $\mathbb{E} X = 0$ and $\mathbb{E} Y < 0$.

For (3): You should see the relation with (1).

For (4): Show you can have $Y > 0$ a.s. and $X< 0$ a.s., and vice-versa. What does it give for the medians?

For (5): patch all of the above together.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think about different variations of what X and Y are allowed to be given our assumptions. In particular, compare cases when $X$ is either identically zero or uniformly distributed, and $Y$ is identically $-2$ or $+2$. See if you can generate counter examples by using these.